# Is the Death Star’s gravitational force strong enough to hold an atmosphere?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope, death-star

The Death Star is the size of a small moon. Endor being a moon (not sure if it's small or not) has a rich atmosphere.

Could the Death Star hold a nitrogen/oxygen based atmosphere with its gravity?

(Now re-reading my question, I suppose this sounds a lot like the plot of SpaceBalls... that was not my intention)

Comment: It's not the size that matters, it's the *mass*.

Comment: Also, it has fake gravity inside it.

Comment: There are two questions here; "What the mass of the Death Star" (on-topic) and "what mass do you need to hold a breathable atmosphere" (off-topic).

Comment: If you apply real physics, the acceleration from flying the ship around would be enough to strip it of atmosphere. So you'd need artificial gravity or similar magic rendering the question of having enough mass moot. Also consider Mars not having retained an atmosphere.

Comment: Do we actually know that there was an atmosphere *around* the Death Star, as opposed to *inside* of the Death Star?

Comment: @Thebluefish - I would think that the Death Star has relatively little mass - it is mostly hollow, compared to an actual moon, which is made of more or less solid rock.

Comment: Endor is a moon, but I have it on good authority that the Death Star is no moon.

Comment: @Thebluefish actually, both do.  The mass for the "amount" of gravity, and the size to determine the surface gravity.  "matters".  Heh.  I see what you did there.

Comment: Endor is, or was originally, the moon of a gas giant (I vaguely remember that the gas giant no longer exists, but that could be wrong).  As such it *could* easily be Earth-sized, and I'd tend to assume it *is* Earth-sized in the absence of evidence to the contrary.

Comment: @zwol - Wookieepedia says that the moon of Endor is about 5,000 kilometers in diameter, which is less than half the diameter of earth, but I don't know how reliable the sources are.  It also says that the rumors about the **planet** of Endor having been destroyed aren't true.  It is still there (I think the moon would have drifted off into space if its planet suddenly disappeared).

Comment: *Obviously* all space ships in star wars have their own atmosphere surrounding because we can *hear* them: http://coolcosmos.ipac.caltech.edu/ask/241--Can-you-hear-sound-in-space- </sarcasm>

Comment: @CodesInChaos - Mars may have lost its atmosphere in large part because of a catastrophic collision with a body the size of Pluto. It may have lost its atmosphere because its core solidified early in its history, stripping away its protective magnetic field. It may have lost its atmosphere because of the cumulative effects of many meteor and comet impacts over billions of years. It may have had an atmosphere composed of light gases that dispersed more easily than the gases in our atmosphere do. Chances are it was a combination of some or all of these factors.  We don't really know yet.

Comment: @corsiKa You win at the internet today. Congrats.

Comment: @WadCheber - You can see the Planet Endor in the background in [this shot](http://img4.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20070811234822/starwars/images/thumb/9/9c/Endor_matte.jpg/640px-Endor_matte.jpg) from SW

Comment: @Corsika - If it's no moon, then what the devil is it?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

According to various sources including the fun, but alas non-canon [Death Star Technical Companion](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Death_Star_Technical_Companion) and the [Star Wars: A New Hope Junior Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_IV:_A_New_Hope_(junior_novelization)), the radius of the Death Star was somewhere between 120km and 160km. The outer frame was comprised of [quadanium steel](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Quadanium_steel) and the interior was a mixture of quadanium steel and other metals.

Assuming the interior is completely solid metal (which it isn't) and presuming quadanium steel is similar in density to normal steel (which we don't know) then we can [calculate](http://www.world-builders.org/lessons/less/les1/gravity.html) that the Death Star has a maximum apparent gravity of around 0.04% of Earth normal.

This would be well below the point that any celestial body could retain a breathable oxygen/nitrogen atmosphere. There simply wouldn't be [sufficient gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_escape) to hold it in place.

Comment: Note that this is further complicated by the presence of massive "gravity generators" and substantial amounts of "gravity plating" on each deck. Who the hell knows how much they weigh?

Comment: Note also that the fact that it can enter hyperspace would probably muck up its ability to hold an atmosphere, even if the gravity wasn't a problem.

Comment: According to the Star Wars Wiki: "The Death Star's interior followed two orientations. Those areas closest to the surface were built with concentric decks with gravity oriented towards the Death Star's core. Past this shell of surface "sprawls", the Death Star's interior had stacked decks with gravity pointing toward the station's southern pole." ... which suggests gravity of ~1 G at the surface unless it was nullified by more (upside down?) gravity generators.

Comment: In Ep IV one or more of the Rebel pilots crashed onto the surface of the Death Star after losing control of their ships. So perhaps there was a gravitational force pulling them down? I think the RotJ novelization mentions the Executor SSD falling into the Death Star II's gravity well after losing its stabilizers in the Battle of Endor.

Comment: @Richard Zenoma Sekot was able to travel through hyperspace so retaining an atmosphere is possible in that dimension ;)

Comment: @RobertF - Yes, it's clear that there's surface gravity. It's presented pretty inconsistently in the films, though.

Comment: @Richard - +1 for saying what I said but taking a fraction of the time and space I did.

Comment: FYI, the effect of increasing density due to pressure on this estimate, extrapolating from the Earth, is less than 100%.  So the surface gravity is <0.08% (assuming the 0.04% was derived reasonably).

Comment: According to *Lost Stars*, the Death Star has sufficient pull that ship thrusters need to be adjusted for the sort of takeoff more common on planets. But whether that indicates that it’s more massive than simple estimates would indicate, or that 0.04g  is enough to have to adjust thrusters (certainly possible) is unclear.

Comment: Also, I think it would be worth editing this to mention the points about the atmosphere being sealed in (as mentioned in a few books), suggesting that (regardless of its gravitational strength from any source) it’s not strong enough to hold a natural atmosphere.

Answer (score 8):

In terms of natural gravity (the mass of the actual physical structure of the Death Star and everything on/in it, without taking into consideration any technological devices that create artificial gravity), certainly not.

The Death Star isn't even the size of a small moon in the sense that most of us think of moons (rocky objects of roughly spherical shape), by the standards of our solar system.  The Death Star II was only about 100/160 kilometers miles in diameter, and the first one was even smaller.  As you can see in [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Solar_System_objects_by_size) list of Solar System objects by size, the only objects with a diameter of 160 kilometers are asteroids, not moons (this list uses radius, which is half of the diameter of the object, so we're looking for objects with a radius between 50 and 80 kilometers).  None of these objects have an atmosphere.

A moon that size wouldn't have enough mass to form a sphere, let alone build up and hold on to an atmosphere.  Rocky objects that size are lumpy and randomly shaped, often referred to as "potato shaped", for reasons that I don't fully understand.  And these objects are, of course, more or less solid rock, with little or no negative space inside, and relatively few cavities.

The Death Star, on the other hand, is full of negative space.  It is mostly hollow, at least relative to a moon, because it has to be:  it is a space station manned by hundreds of thousands of men and droids, and has living quarters, recreation areas, maintenance areas, utility areas, storage, command facilities, battle stations, etc, etc, etc.

Without artificial gravity of some kind, a mostly hollow structure like this would be incapable of holding on to an atmosphere on the surface - it simply doesn't have enough mass.  If, however, it was airtight (which it presumably was) it would have to contain an artificial atmosphere, since we never see anyone inside wearing oxygen masks.

This does indeed seem to be the case.  When the Star Destroyer crashes into it, we see what looks like violent outgassing (at least, that's what I think is going on), suggesting that there is little or no atmosphere on the surface, and the pressure inside is much higher than the near-vacuum of space outside.

However, this is science fiction, not the present day state of technology.  We couldn't build something like the Death Star, and we can't create artificial gravity, but the people in the Galaxy Far, Far Away can do both of these things.  So really, all bets are off.

The first Death Star was completed when it was destroyed, but the second one was apparently less than half finished.  It was bigger than the first, but probably had less mass at the time it was destroyed, because most of the living areas and non-essential facilities were not built yet.  It seemed to have only a skeleton crew, so to speak - enough men to man the battle stations and do the construction work, but not much more than that.  Less men means less space needs to be airtight and filled with breathable air.  Less of the outer shell being in place means the area that *could* be pressurized is much smaller.

One might argue that the construction teams needed air while they were building the damn thing, but I would imagine that much of the work on the outer portions of the station was performed by droids.

But in any case, since this is science **fiction**, they can basically do whatever the writers want or need them to do.  So is it *possible* that the exterior of the Death Star had an atmosphere?  Of course.  But if it did, it was because of some sort of artificial gravity technology, not because of the natural mass of the structure itself.  And I'm not sure why they would need an atmosphere outside the shell of the Death Star - I don't think anyone goes out there very often.  All the good stuff is inside.

On the scientific side of the question, I found [an interesting article](http://passporttoknowledge.com/lfm/ask/atmosphere/Conditions_for_a_planet_to_retain_an_atmosphere.txt) about the conditions necessary for an astronomical object to maintain an atmosphere, as explained by a member of the Mars Pathfinder team.

Comment: About the eighth paragraph... Well, that's really difficult to say, some sources say the DSI had a radius of 140-160 km, while the DSII is said to be between 160-900 km of radius. Even in the worst case scenario (140 vs 160 km), if the DSII was completed at 67% (which seems reasonable by the pictures), it would still be slightly more massive.

Comment: @AlfredoHernández - it seems to me that even if, as you say, 67% of the exterior shell is complete in RotJ (I think it is considerably less than that, maybe 50% or so, but we never see the back half of it, so we don't know), we can still assume that much of the internal structure and hardware is not in place yet.  Most of the crew and the nonessential facilities aren't there (living quarters, recreational areas, utilities and maintenance, food and water supplies, etc), and most of the decks aren't finished, or even close to being finished.

Comment: @AlfredoHernández - we don't even know if it can move yet- it just kind of sits there above Endor.  It doesn't have its own internally generated shields yet, which is why it has to stay near Endor.  I would guess that maybe as little as 30-40% of the total mass is present.  And as far as I can tell, pretty much everyone in the know says the 900 kilometer diameter is absurd.  It was slightly bigger than the original Death Star, but certainly not 6 times bigger.  It would be nice if there was some way to compare the two on the same scale, but I don't see any way to do that.

Comment: @AlfredoHernández - And if the first one was between 140-160 kilometers in diameter, and the second one was between 160-900 kilometers in diameter, there is a chance that both were 160 kilometers in diameter.  That is definitely more likely than the second Death Star being 6 times bigger than the first.  The movies themselves only tell us that the second one was more powerful than the first.  It never says the second was 6 times bigger, which is such a significant fact that it would be strange for them to omit it from the story.

Comment: It is absolutely ridiculous that Wookieepedia's entry on "Death Star" says the second one was 900 kilometers in diameter, while the entry on "Death Star II" says it was 160 kilometers in diameter.  Someone needs to ask George Lucas himself and settle the matter once and for all.

Comment: @AlfredoHernández I found this picture of the actual model of the Death Star used in the movie- it doesn't look like it is anywhere near 67% complete.  http://i.imgur.com/s4zVh3e.jpg. There are a few more pictures of it in here: http://m.imgur.com/a/Zt9Y4

Comment: knowing GL, even he doesn't know the actual size.

Answer (score 3):

Well let's consider what we need in order to have an atmosphere: **Gravity**. You could think of an atmosphere as a world-wide version of tug-of-war. Various forces are pushing the gases out, while gravity is pulling those same gases back in. So we would need sufficient gravity to keep an atmosphere, and in this case, *size doesn't matter*. We can't judge the gravity exerted by this space station just by the fact that it appears to be the size of a small moon.

The first issue at hand is that the artificial gravity within the Death Star doesn't appear to center around the Death Star. As we can see in Star Wars (*Episode 4*), the gravity actually appears to be perpendicular to the center of mass. With that, we cannot correlate any internal gravity with its external gravity.

Now we know that the Death Star has [thermal exhaust ports](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Thermal_exhaust_port) to pump the excess heat from the core reactor. Based on the design and appearance of these exhaust ports, we could infer that they likely expel a heated gas. However it wouldn't make much sense to expel a heated gas if the Death Star had the kind of atmosphere that would keep it all in. Essentially, this would cook the Death Star from both inside *and* outside since there would be no place for this heat to go. This makes me believe that it **does not** maintain the gravity necessary to maintain such an atmosphere, except....

We have explosions happening on the surface of the Death Star. Depending on how much you wish to attribute to movie magic, we could probably wave this off, but let's assume it's how things actually worked. There was definitely *fire* resulting from these, and so we would have to assume that there was oxygen to fuel the flame. What makes this even more confusing is the fact that there are several breaches into the interior, where oxygen exists, but there is no vacuum. So either they had a way of containing these very quickly **or** there was an atmosphere on the exterior sufficient enough for there to be no pressure difference.

The fact that we need specifically shielded airlocks compounds this even more because we wouldn't need them if the Death Star had enough of an atmosphere to make it negligible. More than likely, this atmosphere is either partial (ie, it covers only *some* of the surface of the Death Star), or is held by forces weak enough for the atmosphere to be expelled at some rate.

Based on these two conflicting pieces, I would say that the Death Star **does maintain an atmosphere**, just not a very good one.

Comment: I think we can see outgasing in some scenes, which means the pressure inside is greater than the pressure outside.  The flames could be fed by the outgasing itself.  And there might be breaches in the pressure seal in areas we don't see onscreen, or even in places where there are no crewmen.