# How fast were the X-wing fighters flying in the trench during the Battle of Yavin?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope

> "We're going in, we're going in full throttle, that ought to keep those fighters off our back!"
>   —Luke Skywalker
>
> <sub>*Star Wars Episode IV: A New Hope*</sub>

During Luke's attack run on the Death Star during the Battle of Yavin in *A New Hope*, we see his target computer counting down numbers, presumably distance to the target, until he switches it off.

Do we have any indication of how fast he was flying, either through this or from other clues?

Was that any different from the speed of the group of Y-wings or the first group of X-wings?

Comment: Asking about the Y-Wing speed seems like a separate question to me.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot but closely related. I can very well imagine an answer answering both from the same source. I put it in _here_, instead of asking a separate question and having it closed a dupe. I've reworded it.

Comment: As is usual with vehicles in any work of fiction, they fly at the speed of plot. ;)

Comment: Am I the only on thinking that in space, if the thrust output of an engine remains constant, then the vehicle _accelerates_ at a constant rate. In Space there is no _top speed_ there is only _top acceleration_, applied continually until one approaches light-speed . . . or does the `star-wars` tag imply no actual physics?

Comment: Probably the same reason fighters bank in space.

Comment: @StephenCollings - Because of the excellent interest rates?

Answer (score 5):

The countdown numbers on the targeting computer give us a metric to calculate the speed of each attack run. By simply looking at the amount that the countdown has dropped in one second, you can work out the speed.

- The first attack run (Y-Wings) take place at a speed of 2400 m/s.
- The second attack run (X-Wings) takes place at a speed of 2200 m/s.
- Interestingly, Luke's attack run (at "*full throttle*") actually takes place at a lower speed; 1900 m/s (timestamp 0:19 - 0:20 in the attached video) slowing to 1700 m/s as he approaches the target. This may because the initial part of the run was faster but he's slowed down while Ben is communicating with him and entreating him to use the Force.

---

On a related note, the X-Wing is *supposedly* capable of a maximum subluminal speed of 100 MGLT (megalight per hour).

Assuming a megalight is 1 millionth of lightspeed (1000 kph) then the top speed for an X-wing in free space would be 100,000 kph or approximately 2700 m/s. **This would imply that Luke was at about half-throttle at the end of his attack run.**

[image]

Comment: Where did you get the speeds for the attack runs of the Y-Wings and X-Wings? All I see at the timestamps you mentioned are numbers displaying the distance to target, I don't see any indication of speed anywhere. Or even anything to indicate what unit of measurement is used to display the distance.

Comment: @Sava - The measurements are in metres, according to the Official Fact Files. So by simply looking at the amount that the countdown has dropped in one second, you can work out the metres/second.

Comment: You've got some unit dissonance here. Either the speed can't be megalights per hour, or megalights have to be a unit of distance, not speed.

Comment: @Rawling - MGLT is presumably *per hour*.

Comment: Best answer EVAR!

Comment: Great answer! Just wanted to add a comment explaining the speed discrepancy, though. The X-Wings were going faster on the first two passes because they were making an _attack run_, versus the Y-Wings which were making a _bombing run_. Their original mission was to distract the cannon placements while the Y-Wings made the trench run. Once the Y-Wings were taken out, Luke's "full throttle" comment was meant to indicate speeding down into the trench, then slowing down for the actual bombing part at the end of the trench.

Answer (score 1):

The only place where I remember seeing any mention of speed for X-Wings, or any Star Wars starships in general, has been on the various RPG resources published over the years, which are surprisingly coherent on the subject.

According to both that **Star Wars D6 Core Rulebook edition 2.5** (page 249) and the **Star Wars Saga: Starships of the Galaxy** supplement (page 152) , X-Wings have a maximum speed of 1050 km/h.

Y-Wings are slightly slower at 1000 km/h, while the standard Tie fighter seen at Yavin (dubbed *Tie/ln* in the RPG supplement to avoid confusion with other TIE models) can reach 1200 km/h, making Luke's assumption rather dubious.

While speeds are never mentioned on-screen, we do see the squadron of TIE fighters led by Dark Vador gain on the Y-Wings and X-Wings running up the trench, even though they flew at top speed, proving that the standard TIE fighter is indeed faster, though not by much given how long it took them to catch up with the Rebel crafts.

Comment: I like it how _Darth Vader_ becomes _Dark Vador_ in French. During my first few years in France I actually thought that it was some cheap rip-off of the original Vader.

Comment: That's slow AF, crazy

Comment: How do they leave orbit with this slow velocity? ANH clearly shows that. If gravity and planet/moon size is comparable to earth they need at least 8 km/sec (!) to get (and stay) in low orbit. Source: https://what-if.xkcd.com/58/

Comment: @PeterParker: Lucas don't know jack about physics.

Comment: @PeterParker - You are, of course, failing to take into account that they have anti-gravity, which means that escape velocity is basically meaningless.

Comment: @Valorum - thanks Supreme Chancellor! I always forget about the "higher physics" still in cosmic dimensions the journey to the death star will take them days perhaps weeks (again comparing earth-moon distance as a reference)

Comment: Think you mean 1050 and 1200 as opposed to 1.05 and 1.2 Average walking speed is 5 km/h which those numbers suggest a slow moving storm trooper could out pace the x wing. Vader would have been better getting out and running :)

Comment: In fact if you google speed of an x-wing the first answer confirmed the 1050 Kph number given in this answer.

Comment: Having an upper speed limit for a spacecraft is completely ridiculous.

Comment: @RichardC in a _lot_ of countries, the dot rather than the comma is used as a thousands separator.

Comment: @OrganicMarble - That kph figure is the in-atmosphere maximum speed.

Comment: @Valorum so it's inapplicable to the trench scene.

Comment: @OrganicMarble - Indeed. And we've already confirmed that the Death Star doesn't have an atmosphere; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/92401/is-the-death-star-s-gravitational-force-strong-enough-to-hold-an-atmosphere